# How to remove the history in the URL in jQuery Mobile RC2?

Tags: jquery-mobile, transition

I'm using jQuery mobile RC2. I need to change page from one page to another page without tracking it in history.

I'm using `$.mobile.changePage("#searchPage", "pop", false, false);`

**For Example:**

> Actual : /DefaultSP.aspx#searchPage
>
> Expected : /DefaultSP.aspx(need to
>   remove #searchPage in URL)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if they changed the markup on how to use this but here are the Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/api/methods.html

JS

```
//transition to the "confirm" page with a "pop" transition without tracking it in history           
$.mobile.changePage( "../alerts/confirm.html", {
    transition: "pop",
    reverse: false,
    changeHash: false
});
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/MGdm2/10/

JS

```
$('#customNav').click(function() {
    //transition to the "confirm" page with a "pop" transition without tracking it in history            
    $.mobile.changePage( "#page2", {
        transition: "pop",
        reverse: false,
        changeHash: false
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">

        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Home Page</li>
            <li><a id="customNav">Page 2 (Click here)</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="content">

        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="b" data-dividertheme="e">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Page 2 will not be history</li>
            <li><a href="#home">Home Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Page 3 (Click here)</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page3" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header" data-rel="back"> 
        <h1>clicking the back button should go to home page</h1> 
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">

        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Page 3 (Click the back button in the header)</li>
            <li><a href="#home">Home Page</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

so, what's wrong to do

```
document.location.href = document.location.pathname;
```

Comment: That adds a history state which OP wanted to avoid. Also, wouldn't that bypass the jQuery Mobile framework entirely?